# What exactly is an "info > 0" error for cgesv in lapack?

Tags: fortran, lapack

I'm trying to use lapack to solve a set linear equations, but when I run the program I get an error which is info > 0. It states that

> Element U(10011001) is exactly zero. The factorization
>    has been completed, but the factor U is exactly singular, so the
>    solution could not be computed.'

What does this exactly mean? I'm using the cgesv subroutine. I have a 1001 by 1001 matrix for A and B and X are 1001 by 1. What does the "info > 0 error" actually mean in simple terms?

Comment: This is more a linear algebra question than a computational one, perhaps.  Do you know about conditions on solutions of linear equations?

Comment: I'm not too sure what you mean by that, so no, sorry! I'm kinda confused by what the error message actually means and I couldn't find anything online, so I thought I'd ask the lovely StackOverflow Community! :)

Comment: Related reading http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/702951/easiest-way-to-solve-system-of-linear-equations-involving-singular-matrix   (especially the part about non-unique solution and a free variable) https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LU_decomposition#LU_factorization_with_Partial_Pivoting

Answer (score 0):

It means that your coefficient matrix is not invertible and the solution is not found. The error comes from the initial LU factorization of the coefficient matrix. And the last diagonal element of U turns out to be zero.